# tcp/ip port exhaustion with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, urllib2, tcp

I'm working on a suite of tests using selenium webdriver (written in Python).  The page being tested contains a form that changes its displayed fields based upon what value is selected in one of its select boxes.  This select box has about 250 options.  I have a test (running via nose, though that's probably irrelevant) that iterates through all the options in the select box, verifying that the form has the correct fields displayed for each selected option.

The problem is that for each option, it calls through selenium:

- click for the option to choose
- find_element and is_displayed for 7 fields
- find_elements for the items in the select box
- get_attribute and text for each option in the select box

So that comes out to (roughly) 250 * (7 * 2 + 1 + 2 * 250), or 128,750 distinct requests to the webdriver server the test is running on, all within about 10 or 15 minutes.  This is leading to client port exhaustion on the machine running the test in some instances.  This is all running through a test framework that abstracts away things like how the select box is parsed, when new page objects are created, and a few other things, so optimizations in the test code either mean hacking that all to hell or throwing away the framework for this test and doing everything manually (which, for maintainability of our test code, is a bad idea).

Some ideas I've had for solutions are:

- Trying to somehow pool or reuse the connection to the webdriver server
- Somehow tweaking the configuration of `urllib2` or `httplib` at runtime so that the connections opened by selenium timeout or are killed more quickly
- System independent (or at least implementable for all systems with an OS switch or some such) mechanism for actively tracking and closing the ports being opened by selenium

As I mentioned above, I can't do much to tweak the way the page is parsed or handled, but I do have control over subclassing/tweaking `WebDriver` or `RemoteConnection` any way I please.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach any of the above ideas, or any ideas that I haven't come up with?

Comment: There are a few ways to fix it: 1. Use HTTP 1.1 keepalive connections and reuse them. 2. make the client port range larger (see your OS documentation how, on windows its net tcp), 3. add some sleeps, as the client ports can be reused after around 2 minutes usually

Comment: @schlenk I considered those options, but: 1. Not sure what I'd need to tweak in the webdriver internals to use a keepalive 2. upping the max ports becomes a custom configuration for machines that these tests will run on, making them less portable and harder to setup (and changing the timeout, at least in Windows, can only be done globally from what I've seen) 3. This test already takes 10+ minutes for a relatively small and simple validation; adding sleeps, especially if they aren't at least dynamically triggered by detecting port exhaustion, just makes the test have a longer runtime

Answer (score 2):

In as much as a small amount of plastic explosive solves the problem of forgetting your house keys, I implemented a solution.  I created a class that tracks a list of resources and the time they were added to it, blocks when a limit is reached, and removes entries when their timestamp passes beyond a timeout value.  I then created an instance of this class setup with a limit of 32768 resources and a timeout of 240 seconds, and had my test framework add an entry to the list every time `webdriver.execute()` is called or a few other actions (db queries, REST calls) are performed.  It's not particularly elegant and it's quite arbitrary, but at least so far it seems to be keeping my tests from triggering port exhaustion while not noticeably slowing tests that weren't causing port exhaustion before.

Comment: Three years later, I am afraid nothing has changed, and this is as elegant as it gets. +1

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. I'll post my solution as well for future references (although it most likely is not as good as yours, but it's basic, and I can't be arsed to waste my time on this).

I have no idea why Selenium creates new socket for each javascript call. Sounds like architecture issue.

This makes any type of crawling very hard, and will also fail lengthy integration tests.

Some potential fixes:

1) Start using linux instead - I read somewhere that one dude had this port exhaustion only on windows system. Obviously, not that good solution.

2) Follow msdn article for avoiding tcp/ip port exhaustion, this did it for me. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx

Namely, you should increase `MaxUserPort`, and decrease `TcpTimedWait`. These can be modified without administrator access, perhaps your test could include registry checks for these settings.

3) Create new class which lets older tcp connections to die:

```
public class LoanCrawlerSpeedController : ILoanCrawlerSpeedController
{
    private DateTime _lastCheckpointTime = DateTime.Now;

    public void Checkpoint()
    {
        var currentCheckpointTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (currentCheckpointTime - _lastCheckpointTime > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(32));
            _lastCheckpointTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Each call to selenium, which triggers new tcp/ip port, should use that method(`Checkpoint()`).

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue created in selenium repo:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4162
with some workaround inside:

[Option1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4162#issuecomment-472029006)

[Option2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4162)